# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm having trouble getting training and test data. I classified the data into seven types. Then we created a function that combines the data again. However, when I run it, the training data is None and I get the following error message:

`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Please tell me what to do (variable data's shape is `(len(data),2))`

```
    def get_train_And_test(self, data, percent = 80):
        if percent > 100 :
            print('파라미터를 확인해주세요')
            return 
        target1=[]
        trainx=[]
        testx=[]
        criteria1=0
        for i in range(7):
          target1.append([])    
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i, 0] < 0.5 and data[i, 1] < 0.5 :
                target1[0].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 0] >= 0.5 and data[i, 1] < 0.5 :
                target1[1].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 0] < 0.5 and data[i, 1] >= 0.5 :
                target1[2].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 0] >= 0.5 and data[i, 0] < 0.75 and data[i,1]>=0.5 and data[i,1]<0.75:
                target1[3].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 0] >= 0.5 and data[i, 0] < 0.75 and data[i,1] >= 0.75:
                target1[4].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 1] >= 0.5 and data[i, 0] >= 0.75 and data[i,1] < 0.75:
                target1[5].append(data[i])
            elif data[i, 0] >= 0.75 and data[i, 1] >= 0.75:
                target1[6].append(data[i])
        for i in range(7):
          criteria = int(len(target1[i]) * percent / 100)
          trainx.extend(target1[i][0 : criteria])
          testx.extend(target1[i][criteria: ])
          criteria1+=criteria
        np.random.shuffle(trainx);np.random.shuffle(testx);
        print('기준 ', criteria1)
        return (trainx,testx)

    (x_train, x_test) = analysis.get_train_And_test(data, 80)
    print(x_train[0:4])
```

Result:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-cbab7c630a54> in <module>()
      1 (x_train, x_test) = analysis.get_train_And_test(data, 80)
----> 2 print(x_train[0:4])
      3 (t_train, t_test) = analysis.get_train_And_test(encoded_target, 80)
      4 print(t_train[0:4])
      5 (x_train2, x_test2) = analysi2.get_train_And_test(data2, 80)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a traceback from that code.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is that code wrong?
Why does trainx have a None value?

Comment: Is `data` empty?

Comment: @Márcio Coelho no variable 'data' have 250

Comment: Can you please give as a sample of `data`to test?